# What is an Android Support Library?

Tags: android, android-support-library

What is the purpose of an Android Support Library?

Does this mean `http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html`?

Currently my app minSdkVersion is restricted to level 10.

I am trying to use `ViewPager`, which is not available for a higher API (for example for level 16)...

What does this support library mean? Does it mean I can use `ViewPager`, and the user of the phone with API level less than 16 can still see `ViewPager` widget?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the description of the support library:

> The Support Package includes static "support libraries" that you can
>   add to your Android application in order to use APIs that are either
>   not available for older platform versions or that offer "utility" APIs
>   that aren't a part of the framework APIs. The goal is to simplify your
>   development by offering more APIs that you can bundle with your
>   application so you can worry less about platform versions.

Off course you have to use only the lower SDK available functions.
You should also look the Google Support Library thats make available some new functions for older SDK.
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: i am not sure what you meant by i have to use only the lower sdk available functions, i mean i have the support library, i should be able to use ViewPager, isn't it?  o

Answer (score 8):

Yes, support package will allow you to use most of the fragment widgets back to Android 1.6. With `NineOldDroids` (http://nineoldandroids.com/) and other packages such as `ActionBarSherlock` (http://actionbarsherlock.com/) from the same developer, you can get a lot of the goodies from ICS and above to work on old Android devices.

All you have to do is to import the compatibility libraries. The way they work is that for the new devices, they will use official Android API, for the old ones, they will simulate and run them in compatible ways, so things may look different.

Comment: so viewpager would still look like view pager in lower sdk device but used by simulated by other UI?

Comment: @Edison thanks for the pointer to NineOldDroids and ActionBarSherlock! :-)